# =INT is returning '#VALUE!'

Tags: excel, excel-formula, integer

I'm running INT on `February 12, 2022 09:45 AM` and it's returning `#VALUE!`

[image: Shown here]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? it's formatted as a date.

Comment: Since the data appears to be left-alligned I got a feeling it's actually text instead of date-time values. If these texts appear in recognizable format then try `=INT(--E2)` instead. Or better, handle the culprit and make sure that however you gain this data is in the right data-type.

Comment: Thanks for your response, didn't work though. Same #VALUE! returned

Comment: Probably means the format isn't recognizable for Excel to format into date-time values through double unary.

Comment: What is your Excel Version ?

Comment: Do you specifically need formula? But I found you can resolve this using Text To Columns using Fixed width

Comment: Version 16.65 for Mac.

No I don't have to use this formula. Need to split dates so I can aggregate based on month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can try using a formula,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=DATE(MID(E2,FIND(",",E2)+2,4),MONTH(LEFT(E2,FIND(" ",E2)-1)&1),MID(E2,FIND(" ",E2)+1,2))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Text-To-Columns`:

- Select your data in `E2:E10` or whatever row;
- Go to `Text-To-Columns`, then use `Fixed Width`;
- In the next screen remove all boundaries but keep the one that seperates the date from the timevalue;
- In the next screen choose to format the 1st column on Date 'MDY' and make sure that the destination is `F2`, also choose to Skip the 2nd column;
- Done.

If need be, format the data as general to show the integers only.